# BigQuery streaming insert with deduplication only writes one row

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm using the Go BigQuery library and the [ValueSaver interface](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#ValueSaver) to perform a streaming insert to a table. I'm using a single field as an insert key to cause a dedupe, since it's possible that two processes will be trying to write the same data (Cloud Run with 3 instances triggered by a PubSub subscription where a 2nd process might pick up the message and start processing before a 1st can write).

When the job(s) is/are done, I can see the expected rows in the "Preview" tab of the BigQuery Web UI for the table, however, I can see under "Streaming buffer statistics" that it's still buffered data with "Estimated rows" to be about what I expect, but the "Number of rows" shows 0 and if I query, I only see the first row. All rows on "Preview" have a unique value for the field I'm using as the "InsertId". Eventually (like 90 minutes, as indicated by other questions here), the first row is written to the table and the buffer goes away along with the expected data. If I use `bigquery.NoDedupeID` I get "instant" writes, but duplicate data.

This leads me to two questions, though it's possible I'm missing the point entirely:

1. Am I misunderstanding how the "InsertId" is being used to dedupe data?
2. How do I "close" the insert buffer faster?

Comment: Hi @orbiteleven, Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-streaming) about streaming data using the Storage Write API help you?

Comment: Did the above comment help you?

Comment: Thanks for sending it. It provides an alternative way to do these writes (in Java, but I could rewrite it in Go if need b3), but doesn't really help with the dedupe writes.

Comment: Hi @orbiteleven, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new [GCP support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [Issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).